# How to know which Id belongs to which object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 foreign key ids and they are coming from same table, so they are referenced with table names in the below class, now - how can I know which object refers to which ID - for example the Ids

```
    public partial class InspectionResult
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public InspectionResult()
        {
            this.EventLogs = new HashSet();
            this.InspectionItems = new HashSet();
            this.InspectionResultStatCounts = new HashSet();
            this.NOVs = new HashSet();
            this.UploadedDocuments = new HashSet();
            this.AspNetUsers = new HashSet();
        }

        public int InspectionResultId { get; set; }

        public string EnteredById { get; set; }

        public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser1 { get; set; }
        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser2 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

EnteredById, CreatedByUserId, UpdatedByUserId are coming from same table AspNetUser, but how would I know which Id belongs to AspNetUser, AspNetUser1, ,AspNetUser2 and how to handle AspNetUsers object? I am using EF Database First Approach any help please - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "ForeignKey" data annotation to signify which Id belongs to which navigation property.  I would suggest you name your navigation properties with meaningful names (see below) instead of just 1, 2, 3.

```
public string EnteredById { get; set; }
public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
public string UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("EnteredById")]
public virtual AspNetUser EnteredBy { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
public virtual AspNetUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UpdatedByUserId")]
public virtual AspNetUser UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi thank you - I am using the Database first approach - the field names are created automatically - how can I change it - even if I change it - still when refreshed for something - it will all be overwritten right?

Comment: It's been a while since I have done DB-first, but navigation properties are not part of the database -- they're part of your entity model (in code).  The names of those navigation properties can be anything you want.  You just can't change the regular properties that are part of the DB (EnteredById, CreatedById, etc) since those were generated from your existing DB.